# Show different number of posts on first Blog listing page

Tags: php

I can’t work out how to change the number of posts listing on the first blog page only. I will need to list 4 normal posts on the first page and 6 normal posts on any other page.
I found a few examples on StackExchange but my case is slightly different because I also have Featured post on the first page, which belongs to the Featured category and 4 other normal posts. From the second page on, there is no Featured post showing, only 6 normal posts.

This code works really well with the Featured posts, but can’t find a way to change the number of normal posts showing. Every time I add `new WP_Query()` for the second loop the Featured post stops working.

```
<ul class="grid grid--blog">
    <?php $do_not_duplicate = 0;
        if(!is_paged()):
            $featured = new WP_Query('category_name=featured&posts_per_page=1');
            while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
                <li class="grid__item grid__item-featured"><?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?></li>
            <?php endwhile;
        endif;

        if (have_posts()) : 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
                <li class="grid__item"><?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?></li>
            <?php endwhile; 
        endif; 
    ?>
</ul>
```

and this is the desired layout:

First Blog listing page

[image: first blog listing page]

All the other Blog listing pages

[image: all other blog listing pages]

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while to wrap my head around this, but finally, I made it work. 
I will share my solution here in case someone else is looking to implement a similar layout:

```
<ul class="post preview grid grid--blog">
    <?php $do_not_duplicate = 0 ?>
    <?php if(!is_paged()): ?>
        <?php $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'featured',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        );
        $featured = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured->the_post(); 
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
            <li class="grid__item grid__item-featured"><?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; 
    wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <?php 
    $featuredid = get_cat_ID( 'Featured' );
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    if(!is_paged()) {
        $postsargs = array(
            'posts_per_page'        => 4,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'cat'                   => - $featuredid,
            'paged'                 => $paged
        );
        $allposts = new WP_Query( $postsargs );
    } else {
        $secondPageArgs = array(
            'posts_per_page'        => 6,
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'cat'                   => - $featuredid,
            'paged'                 => $paged
        );
        $allposts = new WP_Query( $secondPageArgs );
    }

    if ( $allposts->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $allposts->have_posts() ) : $allposts->the_post(); 
            if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
            <li class="grid__item"><?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; 
    endif;

    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

So `$do_not_duplicate` makes sure that you don't repeat the Featured post from the first query in the second query when listing all the other posts.

And then wrapping our second query `$allposts` arguments in the IF statement to check on which page those posts are going to be displayed. If we are on the first blog page, `'posts_per_page' => 4` will be called, otherwise `'posts_per_page' => 6` will be called on all the other pages.

Hope it helps!